# How to handle RIO (soap) System.net exception absorbing ERemoteable exception (difference between RIO and Berlin)

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap

We use multiple 3rd party, private, soap webservices and they all work fine in Berlin. 
We just made the switch to rio and noticed the soap webservices behave differently now when it comes to firing ERemotable exceptions. In Berlin We get ERemotable exceptions all the time even if the http response code was 500 (internal server error). For some reason which i'm not sure is valid, the soap webservices we consume return http 500 error when a ERemotable exception will get fired. We have no control over that. However when i run the same code in RIO we noticed that we don't get any ERemoteable exceptions anymore instead we get System.net exceptions with http status code 500 and the eremotable exceptions like they occur in berlin never happen.

This is a difference in behaviour between delphi berlin and rio when not having changed the code.

I found out the system.net exception gets fired in `CheckResponseError` in `Soap.SOAPHTTPTRans.pas` file and that there is an event `FOnHttpError`, which can be set using `SetOnHttpError` procedure. It's also possible to change the Result from heaError to heaSuccess using the last var `Action` parameter in that event.

If i add such event like this which makes the http 500 errors be considered still a success i do get the ERemotable exceptions again, and not the system.net exceptions, as those only get fired when the result is heaError:

```
procedure TBaseEnotWebserviceClient.HttpError(const HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp; const HTTPResponse: IHTTPResponse;
  const Error: ESOAPHTTPException; var Action: TSOAPHttpErrorAction);
begin
  if HTTPResponse.StatusCode = 500 then
    Action := heaSuccess;
end;
```

Now while this works i wonder if this could have a negative impact, and i also wonder if berlin did not produce any http errors when dealing with soap but just went further in the code and fired an eremotable exception when needed.

May main question is, how can i make rio act the same again as berlin is the code i supplied to ignore the http 500 error enough or should i consider other result codes to be successfull as well to get same behaviour as we had in berlin. It seems to me in rio the ERemotable Exception that can get absorbed by the System.net exceptions (from CheckResponse function) and i don't really know how to correctly work around this issue se we get all ERemotable exceptions again

Edit: Just noticed this in source code of `Soap.SoapHttpTrans` in berlin. It seems in berlin they ignored the http 500 status codes while they don't do this anymore in rio. 
[image: berlin ignores http 500]

while rio they now only have this:
[image: rio does not ignore http 500]